# Java define Generic Class param with a const or static method

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to improve my code especially my way to use Generic classes.
In my project I have about 30 classes like folowing :

```
GenericEntity<T extends Serializable>{

    protected T id;
    public T getId(){ return id;};
...
}

public class A extends GenericEntity<Integer>{
    ...
}


public interface IService<T extends GenericEntity, T extends Serializable>{
...
}

public class AService extends IService<A,Integer>{
...
}
```

I would like to specify the class of my entity Id only one time instead of one in GenericEntity and one in Service like that.

```
public class A extends GenericEntity<getIdType()>{
    public final static Class getIdType(){
        return Integer.class;
    }
}

public class AService extends IService<A,A.getIdType()>{
...
}
```

I'm aware it doesn't work like that but I'm hoping there is a way to do it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? When you declare `AService`, you know both `A`'s class and it's ID type.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `IService<S extends Serializable, T extends GenericEntity<S>>`...  And then having `AService implements IService<Integer, A>`?

Comment: I want do that if one day I need to use Long instead Integer I will have about 60 modifications to do it.
I also have Unit tests which need Id types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
class GenericEntity<T extends Serializable>{
    protected T id;
    public T getId(){ return id;};
}

// THESE ARE UNNECESSARY as far as I can tell
class A extends GenericEntity<Integer>{ }
class B extends GenericEntity<Long>{ }

// where U matches the generic type of GenericEntity<?>
interface IService<T extends GenericEntity<?>, U extends Serializable>{ }

class AService extends IService<A, Integer>{ }
class BService extends IService<B, Long>{ }
```

You could do this:

```
class GenericEntity<T extends Serializable> {
    protected T id;
    public T getIdFromEntity() { return id; }
}

// 'IService' can/should only know of 'id' as some type that extends 'Serializeable'
// So if something implements 'IService' then everything knows it will have
// a method with the signature 'T getGenericEntity(Serializable id);'
interface IService<T extends GenericEntity<?>> {
    public T getGenericEntity(Serializable id);
}

// 'AService' knows that 'id' will be an 'Integer'
class AService implements IService<GenericEntity<Integer>> {

    Map<Serializable, GenericEntity<Integer>> entityMap = new HashMap<>();

    void someMethod() {
        GenericEntity<Integer> entity = this.getGenericEntity(Integer.valueOf(1));
        Integer i1 = entity.getIdFromEntity();
        // ... do stuff
    }

    // even though 'AService' knows that 'id' will be an 'Integer'
    // the 'IService' interface defines this as taking a 'Serializable'
    // so it must keep that method signature.
    @Override public GenericEntity<Integer> getGenericEntity(Serializable id) {
        return entityMap.get(id);
    }
}

class BService implements IService<GenericEntity<Long>> {
    @Override public GenericEntity<Long> getGenericEntity(Serializable id) { return null; }
    // ... similar to AService ...
}
```

This would cut out all your excess `class X extends GenericEntity<SOME_TYPE>` classes.

You would only need the one generic `GenericEntity<T extends Serializable>` and the one `interface IService<T extends GenericEntity<?>>`. Also, since they aren't generic `AService` and `BService` know the actual type that extends `Serializeable` (Integer and Long), so they don't need the extra info passed to them in generics.

Since `IService` is generic for any `T extends GenericEntity<?>` it *shouldn't* know a concrete type for `genericEntity.getId()` (*and you probably shouldn't want it to*).  Also you should avoid making it concrete because it's an `Interface`.

The type of `id` as far as `IService` cares is `Serializable`, since `IService<GenericEntity<?>>` implies that the wildcard `?` extends `Serializeable` since `class GenericEntity<T extends Serializeable>` requires it to.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I'm wondering how the service would know the type of entity Id in your example ?
interface IService<T extends GenericEntity<?>> {
    public T getGenericEntity(? id);
}

Comment: @ScorprocS Edited. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes thanks. So in order to get a generic entity by Id I just need to do that.
interface IService<T extends GenericEntity<?>> { public T getGenericEntity(Serializable id); }

Comment: @ScorprocS Exactly. I'll edit the code to include that. If this answer works for you then an 'accept' would be much appreciated.